# angular2 testing using jasmine for subscribe method

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I have a spec code to test like this

```
 it('login test', () => {

      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(component);
      fixture.detectChanges();
      let authService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Auth);
      spyOn(authService, 'login').and.returnValue('');

      const elements = fixture.nativeElement;
      fixture.componentInstance.login();
      expect(authService.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

and the implementation code like this

```
login() {

    this.auth.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(() => {

      }
    });
  }
```

it gives error:

> this.auth.login(...).subscribe is not a function

Why does this error happen?

Answer (score 39):

You need to return something with a `subscribe` method, as the component calls `subscribe` directly from `login`. A string does not. You could just return an object with a `subscribe` function and it should work

```
and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} });
```

Or if you want to pass a real observable, you could

```
and.returnValue(Observable.of('some value'));
```

You might need to import `rxjs/add/observable/of`

Comment: Perfect for me ! Thanks

Comment: For the first option, is there any way of returning a value? Something like this for example : and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => { count: 1000 } });

Comment: @abyrne85 That's straight javascript. `() => { count: 1000 }` sees the curly braces and thinks that's the body of the inline arrow function. But you as the developer know that's for the object you want to return. You need to tell _it_ the same thing. So what you want is `() => ({ count: 1000 })`--or simply, _surround the object in parenthesis_. You can also specify it longer by doing something like `() => { return { count: 1000 }; }` but now that you know the shorter way there's no need for that.

Answer (score 7):

On rxjs v6 you should use `of` instead of `Observable.of` or `Observable.from` e.g

```
const loginService: any = {
    getUser: () => of(['Adam West']),
};
```

and import

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 6):

Change your spy for the 'login' method on your authService to return an observable instead of a value. You'll need to import:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Setup your spy:

```
const loginResult = '';
const spy = spyOn(authService, 'login').and.callFake(() => {
    return Observable.from([loginResult]);
})
```

Call login:

```
fixture.componentInstance.login();
```

Assert:

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```