# Angular2 - Test a function that calls a http service inside

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

I am currently trying to test a function which calls a http request service and then does something in the subscribe part (calls a function and sets a variable). My approach so far was to just call the function and I thought the request-service will be called automatically and so the subscribe part will be executed. However, I feel like this is not the way of doing it as it's not working.

The function I want to test:

```
  public trainBot() {
    this.isTraining = true;
    this.requestsService.trainModel(this.botId, false)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.trainingStatus = this.trainingStatusMapping[response['status']];
        this.pollTrainingStatus();
      });
  }
```

My test so far (which does not work).

```
it('should poll the training status', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'pollTrainingStatus').and.callThrough();
    component.trainBot();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.pollTrainingStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

So, can anyone tell me how to test that part inside the .subscribe(... part?

**Update:**

as someone suggested I added returnValue and async to my test. They are still not working, but looking like that now:

```
it('should poll the training status', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.trainBot();
    spyOn(service, 'trainModel').and.returnValue(Observable.of({'status': 'training'}));
    spyOn(component, 'pollTrainingStatus').and.callThrough();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick(1);
    expect(service.trainModel).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.pollTrainingStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

The Error is the same

Comment: Could you share the error you're receiving or what the output is for the failed test?

Comment: @Kevin "Expected spy pollTrainingStatus to have been called." Which means pollTrainingStatus() was not called

Comment: Check out this question: [angular2 testing using jasmine for subscribe method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080912/angular2-testing-using-jasmine-for-subscribe-method). Let me know if the answer there works for you.

Comment: So I tried to add the '.and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} })' part, but that does not change anything

Comment: I totally just realized, don't you need to spy on `this.requestsService.trainModel` as well?

Comment: @Kevin yeah I added that line: spyOn(service, 'trainModel').and.returnValue(Observable.of({'status': 'training'}));

but that does not work

Comment: `spyOn` commands can't be chained. Get rid of `.and.callThrough()` in the spy on `trainModel`.

Comment: Is `http` or `requestService` mocked in TestBed?

Comment: @buato: yes I have the following line in the beforEach() section:
service = TestBed.get(RequestsService)

I remove the callThrough part() and updated my test above in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, You need to create your Spies BEFORE you run the method trainBot().  That should fix your tests.

```
it('should poll the training status', () => {
  spyOn(service, 'trainModel').and.returnValue(Observable.of({'status': 'training'}));
  spyOn(component, 'pollTrainingStatus');

  component.trainBot();

  expect(service.trainModel).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.pollTrainingStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

However, let's talk about your testing strategies.

To be honest, you're testing a component, not the service, so you shouldn't be letting the service method call through.

```
spyOn(service, 'trainModel').and.returnValue(Observable.of({'status': 'training'}));
```

Additionally, a unit test should test the smallest thing possible.  You're actually testing the callback here, and the callback should probably be a named method instead of an anonymous arrow function. Then you can test and verify the callback's functionality in other tests.

```
public trainBot() {
  this.isTraining = true;
  this.requestsService.trainModel(this.botId, false)
      .subscribe(response => this.onTrainbotSuccess(response));
}

public onTrainbotSuccess(response) {
  this.trainingStatus = this.trainingStatusMapping[response['status']];
  this.pollTrainingStatus();
}
```

In *this* test, you can test that the response method is getting called

```
it('should call service.trainModel', () => {
  spyOn(service, 'trainModel').and.returnValue(Observable.of({'status': 'training'}));

  component.trainBot();

  expect(service.trainModel).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it('should send success responses to onTrainbotSuccess()', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'onTrainbotSuccess');
  spyOn(service, 'trainModel').and.returnValue(Observable.of({'status': 'training'}));

  component.trainBot();

  expect(component.onTrainbotSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Now we can write tests for specifically what the success callback does.

```
it('should poll the training status', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'pollTrainingStatus');

  component.onTrainbotSuccess({'status': 'training'});

  expect(component.pollTrainingStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I got the same condition but it fails for me while calling `component.pollTrainingStatus`. Expected spy pollTrainingStatus to have been called.

Comment: I like how you decomposed the code. But I couldn't help noticing the introduction of a new public method onTrainbotSuccess in spite of making testing possible. Isn't that a bit hacky? Can Jasmine spy on private methods too, or have you compromised encapsulation for testing?

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to `subscribe()` is called asynchronously. This means that your assertion is run before `this.pollTrainingStatus()` is called. You need to use [`async()` or `fakeAsync()` utility function](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-async-function-in-it).

In code can look like this (if using `fakeAsync()`):

```
import { fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

it('should poll the training status', fakeAsync(() => {
  ...
  expect(component.pollTrainingStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Comment: Have you added `tick()` like in [docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-fakeasync-function)?