# testing a service call in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I am trying to write a unit-test for a function that calls a service. But am running into the error: `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor`

What I am trying to test is a service call that, on success, sets the value of the variable 'cards'.

I've created the appropriate mock for the service (CardService), which you can see in the spec file below

**test.component.spec.ts**

```
class MockCardService extends CardService {
    constructor() {
        super(null); // null is the http in service's constructor
    }
    getCardDetails(): any {
        return Observable.of([{ 0: 'card1' }, { 1: 'card2' }]);
    }
}

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    let component: MyComponent;
    let mockCardService: MockCardService;
    beforeEach(() => {
        mockCardService = new MockCardService();
        component = new MyComponent(
            mockCardService // add the mock service that runs before each test
        );
    });

// The failing test :(
it('should set the card variable to the value returned by the service', () => {

    spyOn(mockCardService, 'getCardDetails').and.callThrough();

    // Act
    component.ngOnInit();
    component.updateCards(); // call the function I am testing

    // Assert
    expect(component.cards).toConTainText('Card1');
});
```

And the **component** file with the function I'm testing:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    public cards: CardModel[] = [];
    constructor(
        private cardService: CardService,
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.updateCards(); // call the update card service
    }

    updateCards(): void {
        this.cardService.getCardDetails().subscribe(
            (cardsDetails) => {
                this.cards = cardsDetails;
            },
            (err) => {
                // todo: error handling
                console.log(err);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Whenever this test runs I recieve the error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Observable_1.Observable.of([{ 0: 'card1' }, { 1: 'card2' }])') (line 22)
>   getCardDetails
>   updateCards
>   ngOnInit

And I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, why 'getCardDetals.subscribe' is undefined. The MockCardService class I provided doesn't appear to be working for some reason.

(note that this.cardService.getCardDetails() is defined, if I log it out in the component itself )

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: At a guess, `this.cardService.getCardDetails()` returns the string from your mock, and the string doesn't have a `subscribe` method.  The answers to [angular2 testing using jasmine for subscribe method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080912/angular2-testing-using-jasmine-for-subscribe-method) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author here:

I'm still not sure what is going wrong. But I was able to fix this by changing `class MockCardService extends CardService {` to just `let MockCardService`, and using that variable throughout. Good luck to anyone who runs into this!

Answer (score 0):

`MockCardService.getCardDetails()` should return an Observable, so you can run subscribe in the component.

Comment: I tried changing my mock getCardDetails to return an observable like so: return getCardDetails(): any {
        return Observable.of([{ 0: 'card1' }, { 1: 'card2' }]);
    }   . 


Still gives me the error TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Observable_1.Observable.of([{ 0: 'card1' }, { 1: 'card2' }])')

unfortunantly

Comment: I updated the question with how I tried your solution

Comment: Have you imported Observable? `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` You will need it in the test as well.

Comment: import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx' in both files; , yep, I'm importing it in both the service and the test :(

Comment: updated original post with new error after making it an observable